# Mantener solo las línias que empiezan con ciertos caracteres en fichero linux

Tags: bash, grep

Tengo un fichero que luce así:

```
0   123   word
1   324   word
2   234   word
3   53    word
4   666   word
5   23    word
6   4     word
...
```

He estado intentando mantener las línias que empiezan por ciertos caracteres específicos (o borrar las demás). Los caracteres los cuales especifican las línias a mantener están apuntados en otro fichero con este formato:

```
2
4
5
...
```

Mi idea es que el fichero final se vea así:

```
2   234   word
4   666   word
5   23    word
...
```

He intentado usar el comando grep para mantener las línias que son de mi interés (grep "2" input > output), pero hacerlo uno a uno no es viable y no se como hacerlo para una lista de números dentro de un fichero. Gracias por leer!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Lo otro, Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. Por favor incluye un ejemplo mínimo de lo que has probado y qué errores tienes. Por último, dices "some numbers" pero no es del todo claro si necesitas los números pares o usas algún otro criterio.

Comment: Hola! Primero que todo, perdón por la confusión con el idioma. Gracias por avisar. En referencia al criterio de selección de los números, simplemente necesito las línias que empiezan por los números que aparecen en el fichero, los cuáles no siguen ninguna norma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que lo has probado con `grep`, y se me ha ocurrido esta posible solución combinando `sed` y `grep` para tu caso:

Suponiendo que tienes esos dos archivos, uno llamado *datos.txt* con los datos:

```
0   123   word
1   324   word
2   234   word
3   53    word
4   666   word
5   23    word
6   4     word
```

y otro llamado *numeros.txt* con los números:

```
2
4
5
```

puedes realizar esta combinación de comandos para localizar las líneas que empiezan por esos números en el archivo *datos.txt*:

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]*\)/^\1[[:space:]]/' numeros.txt | grep -f - datos.txt
```

**donde:**

- [*sed*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) es una instrucción que puede realizar búsquedas y reemplazos de cadenas simples o de expresiones regulares, a la cual le pasamos como parámetros un patrón y un archivo para la búsqueda del patrón.

Explicación del patrón:

```
's/\([[:digit:]]*\)/^\1[[:space:]]/'
```

Este patrón se divide en tres partes delimitadas por la barra `/`.

- **`s`**: La primera es la letra **s** que indica que se va a realizar una búsqueda (*search*).
- **`\([[:digit:]]*\)`**: La segunda es la cadena a buscar, en este caso seran todos los digitos que encuentre, por lo tanto seria `[[:digit:]]*`, pero como nos interesa recuperar el dato despues la encerramos entre paréntesis, escapándolos así: `\([[:digit:]]*\)`.  Al encerrarlos entre paréntesis, luego, en la tercera parte, podremos recuperarlo mediante una barra invertida y el número en que aparece (si hubiera varios paréntesis seria `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, etc...
- **`^\1[[:space:]]`**: la tercera parte se corresponde con la cadena de sustitución que vamos a aplicar sobre los elementos coincidentes de la segunda, la cual hemos escrito así:

```
^\1[[:space:]]
```

**donde:**

- `^` forma parte de la *expresión regular* que necesitamos después para pasarle al *grep*, y que indica que lo que venga después tiene que estar al inicio de la línea.
- `\1` como he explicado antes se corresponde con la primera cadena de sustitución entre paréntesis recuperada de la segunda parte.
- `[[:space:]]` tambien forma parte de la expresión regular que le pasamos al *grep* después, y que indica que después del número tiene que venir un espacio, para evitar que se confunda con los otros números de la misma linea que pueda haber.

Dejo aquí [un enlace de las expresiones POSIX con corchetes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), que son las que estamos usando en esta respuesta.

Lo que viene a continuación es el archivo sobre el cual hacemos el **sed**, que es **numeros.txt**.

Todo esto sin más nos generaría esta secuencia de lineas:

```
^2[[:space:]]
^4[[:space:]]
^5[[:space:]]
```

que són las que necesitamos pasarle al **grep** como expresión regular para que encuentre sus coincidencias en el archivo *datos.txt*.

Lo siguiente que vemos en el comando es el símbolo de un pipe (tuberia): `|` que indica que todo lo que este comando haya producido hasta ahora se pasará al siguiente comando que aparezca a continuación en forma de enrtada estandar.

Por lo tanto necesitamos decirle al grep que esas líneas vienen de la entrada estándar lo cual hacemos mediante este parámetro:

```
grep -f -
```

pues tal como dice su [página man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/es/man1/grep.1.html):

> Grep busca en la entrada, bien en la que se le especifica con nombres
> de ficheros o bien en la entrada estándar si no se le dan dichos
> nombres o si uno de éstos consiste en −, líneas que concuerden o
> coincidan con el patrón dado.

Aunque no me convence demasiado esa traduccíon, en el inglés lo ponen así:

> A  FILE  of  “-”  stands  for  standard  input.

Y ahora que ya sabemos como vamos a recibir los patrones del **grep**, tenemos que aplicarlos sobre el archivo de datos.txt, el cual pasamos como último parámetro.

Y al ejecutar la instrucción nos devuelve esto:

```
2   234   word
4   666   word
5   23    word
```

que viene a ser lo que ha preguntado el OP.

Ya nos dirás si te ha servido.

Comment: Gracias! Funciona justo como debería y la explicación es muy clara!

Answer (score 0):

Ya que lo pediste con `grep`, puedes utilizar expresiones regulares tipo Perl para poder resumir mucha verborrea de las expresiones regulares.

Tomemos tu archivo como ejemplo:

```
0   123   word
1   324   word
2   234   word
3   53    word
4   666   word
5   23    word
6   4     word
```

Ahora usemos una expresión regular sencilla de escribir:

```
$ grep -P '^[245]\s+' /tmp/grep_file

 2   234   word
 4   666   word
 5   23    word
```

Lo que pedimos con esta expresión regular es:

- `^`, que al inicio del renglón
- `[245]`, busque alguno de estos caracteres (no todos, sino uno)
- `\s+`, seguido de uno o más espacios

Por supuesto puedes usar otras opciones como `sed` o `awk`.

Usemos `sed`:

```
$ sed -nr '/^[245] /p' /tmp/grep_file
```

Aquí, la expresión regular es similar a la anterior. Lo que hacemos es utilizar `sed` de la forma `/<patron a buscar en cada linea>/<comando imprimir>`

Con los parámetros `-n` pedimos que no imprima por defecto, y con `-r` habilitamos expresiones regulares extendidas.

Con `awk` es más corto:

```
$ awk '/^[245] /' /tmp/grep_file
```

Recuerda que los caracteres encerrados entre corchetes (`[aqui]`), no te buscan la palabra, sino alguno de los caracteres contenidos ahí, o incluso rangos.